# Jetty WebSocket server won't release binary message byte buffer pool

Tags: java, jetty, bytebuffer

I am writing a simple embedded WebSocket server using Jetty's JSR356 WebSocket implementation. My server listens to a local port and a web application will create a WebSocket connection from browser to the local server, and send binary data to server.
Here is my server code example:

**Server:**

```
public class WSServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server();

        // Connector
        ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
        connector.setPort(8080);

        ServletContextHandler ctx = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        ctx.setContextPath("/");

        server.setHandler(ctx);
        server.addConnector(connector);

        try {
            // Initialize javax.websocket layer
            ServerContainer wscontainer = WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext(ctx);

            // Add WebSocket endpoint to javax.websocket layer
            wscontainer.addEndpoint(WSEndpoint.class);
            wscontainer.setDefaultMaxSessionIdleTimeout(0);
            wscontainer.setDefaultMaxTextMessageBufferSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            wscontainer.setDefaultMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

            server.start();
            server.join();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

**Server Endpoint:**

```
@ServerEndpoint("/")
public class WSEndpoint {

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) throws IOException {
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText("onOpen");
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session) {
        System.out.println("Received text message: " + message);
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onBinary(ByteBuffer bb, Session session) {
        System.out.println("Got binary message, do nothing to make sure there is no reference to ByteBuffer and Session");
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) {

    }
}
```

In this example, do nothing to the incoming binary bytebuffer, to avoid any reference to that object for test purpose.

But after some test run with several files transferred, the memory usage of this server is growing significantly, and hardly go down. Even I disconnect the connection, the memory still not down, before I had to stop my server, it takes up to 1.5 GB of memory.

Then I dumped the memory and find out that all the binary files that I had transferred were kept in memory by `org.eclipse.jetty.io.MappedByteBufferPool` object and never released. IMO, Jetty will take care of this MappedByteBufferPool and release the memory at a proper time, since it not exposed to us, but it seems the buffer pool never got released.

So my questions are:

1. Did I do anything wrong in my code?
2. If the code is fine, how to fix this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug fixed in Jetty [`9.3.4.v20151007`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.3.4.v20151007/VERSION.txt#L42) and further refined in `9.3.5.v20151012`.

Relevant bugs:

- Bug [#478829](https://bugs.eclipse.org/478829): WebsocketSession not cleaned up / memory leak
- Bug [#474936](https://bugs.eclipse.org/474936): WebSocketSessions are not always cleaned out from openSessions

Comment: Thanks, but these two bugs seems to be against to Jetty's own WebSocket implementation, not for jsr 356 implementation, looks like my issue is also a bug, maybe I should log a bug too.

Comment: The JSR356 implementation is a layer above the jetty native websocket implementation.

Comment: The latest release 9.3.5.v20151012 still have the same problem though.

Comment: The latest release is actually [9.3.6.v20151106](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-distribution/9.3.6.v20151106/) :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to post the solution that I got from Jetty bug report, thanks for the  replay from @Joakim Erdfelt, for anyone that may have the same problem:

For large file transfer, use stream instead of ByteBuffer:

```
@OnMessage
public void onBinary(InputStream in, Session session) {
    System.out.println("Got binary message");
}
```

But please notice that as my test, this solution works fine for IE and Chrome, but if transfer files from Firefox browser, it still accumulating memory usage by MappedByteBuffer object, at lease for the current latest Jetty version 9.3.6.